# Is a non-nullable, MySQL enum column guaranteed to only contain those values?

Tags: mysql, enums

If I have a column in a MySQL database that is:

- Non-nullable
- Is an ENUM with 5 possible values
- Has a default value of 1 of those ENUM's

Can it be guaranteed that there can never be a value in that column apart from one of those ENUM's?

Comment: Yes. here is some text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default - there is one more value your column can have in addition to the values of the enum, an empty string in the column.

You have to enable strict SQL mode in MySQL to have the guarantee that only the enum values (or NULL   if the column is nullable ) can occur.

Taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html)

> If you insert an invalid value into an ENUM (that is, a string not
>   present in the list of permitted values), the empty string is inserted
>   instead as a special error value. This string can be distinguished
>   from a “normal” empty string by the fact that this string has the
>   numeric value 0. See Section 11.4.4, “ Index Values for Enumeration
>   Literals ” for details about the numeric indexes for the enumeration
>   values.
>
> If strict SQL mode is enabled, attempts to insert invalid ENUM values
>   result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

> If strict SQL mode is enabled, attempts to insert invalid ENUM values result in an error.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html)

Comment: While that answer is correct (MySQL not having basic check constraints), it doesn't address the question whether an `enum` column validates the defined values.